# How to run cron job based on database entries using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my application I am using one functionality which I need to run on a specific time. I saved that time in my database. Based on that my scheduler will run the functionality. Currently I have used cron method which run that functionality every particular minutes. But not run cron at the minutes like 2,3,4 etc. or any other any time. How can I run that? Is there any specific method which take any values and based on that it run cron?

Comment: In laravel "https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/scheduling" is the link from where we can check how to run cron

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, you want to execute a `cron` command on specific date/time? You could do this by using `when` method with closure function inside your schedule cron command, which will execute if given date/time is returned true. Do something like this:

```
$schedule->command('your:command')
            ->when(function(){
               return ('your condition goes here');
            });
```

So if your condition is true, this command will execute.

Comment: Currently I am running that like below,

`$schedule->call(function () use ($input) {
           //Executable code here
}->cron("* * * * *")`


But this works for only minutes/everyminutes/everyfiveminutes etc. But If I add any other parameter like 
`->cron("*/3 * * * *")` or some other conditions then it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you run crob job in 2 ways:

1. write function in controller and write route for that function. and set that function route in cron job.

set cron like this :

```
wget -O -q -t 1 {url of that function}

for example : wget -O -q -t 1 http://domian.com/xyz/advertisement_expire_if_not_print
```

2. using scheduler